# Access storage attached to a PLC via internet

Tags: nas, usb-storage

In the company I work for, there is a [PLC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmable_logic_controller) which logs events to a generic USB flash disk connected to it.

The company which provided and programmed the PLC has closed - so there is no support.

Every Sunday I want to transfer the log file to my laptop. I have to go to the company (32Km), safely unplug it from the PLC, connect it to my Laptop, copy the log file and plug it again to the PLC.

I was wondering if there is any device that can be recognized by the PLC as an USB flash disk, and that can be accessed via internet (maybe via FTP) at the same time.

Comment: Have you looked into using something like RSlogix to connect to the PLC? Or have you tried to dial into it via a Terminal session?